# how to solve this second order pde?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, characteristics

$\frac{\partial^2 X_1}{\partial t^2}+\omega_0^2X_1=2\omega_0(1+a_0exp(-\tau))^{-1.5} Sin(3\omega_0t)$ where $a_0$ and $\omega_0$ are constants.

I tried to solve it using methods of characteristics.

$Au_{xx}+2Bu_{xy}+Cu_{yy}+Du_x+Eu_y+Fu=G(x,y)$

For the pde that I want to solve,
A=1, B=C=D=E=0, F=$\omega_0^2$, G=$2\omega_0(1+a_0exp(-\tau))^{-1.5} Sin(3\omega_0t)$

$B^2-AC=0$

so the pde is parabolic everywhere.

$\frac{d\tau}{dt}=\frac{B}{A}$=c, constant which is just $\epsilon$ since $\tau=\epsilon t$

$\implies$ $\xi=\epsilon$

If $\xi$ is constant then the Jacobian of $\xi$ and $\eta$ will always be 0 no matter what function we choose for $\eta$.

So I don't know how to move on from here.

Comment: Since you have derivatives with respect to one variable only, you could work like it was an ordinary differential equation. Just be careful with constants of integration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume that $w>0$ is a real positive number.

The characteristic equation of an homogeneous equation $$u''+w^2 u=0$$
is $$r^2+w^2 =0$$ which roots are $r=\pm i w$ 
therefore the solution is $$u=a\sin x + b \cos x$$

To solve the inhomogeneous equation $$u''+w^2 u=f(x)$$
one uses either [method of undetermined coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_undetermined_coefficients) or a [variation of parameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variation_of_parameters). The first assumes that the function $f(x)$ can be written in a specific form, the second involves integration of the $\frac{f}{Wronskian}$

Hope this helps.